# Custom SQL functions and Code First (EF 4.1)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using **Entity Framework 4.1 RC** and code first approach.
**How can I call custom SQL functions?**

If I use *EdmFunction* attribute, what namespace should I specify?

```
[EdmFunction("Namespace", "GetAge")] 
public static int GetAge(Person p) 
{  
    throw new NotSupportedException(…); 
}
```

When I try to execute a LINQ query with such function the following exception is thrown:

> The specified method '...' on the type
>   '...' cannot be translated into a LINQ to
>   Entities store expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to call SQL function you must execute a custom SQL query. To do that use context.Database.SqlQuery. Entity framework supports mapping of stored procedures but this feature is not supported in DbContext API (EF 4.1). If you want to call a stored procedure you must again use context.Database.SqlQuery. Stored procedures can't never be used in Linq queries.

`EdmFunction` is feature of ObjectContext API and Entity designer. The namespace is set to the namespace defined in the EDMX file. When using code-first you don't have the EDMX file and you can't define function mapping.

Btw. if you follow the code first approach you should not have any stored procedures or SQL functions because you database is defined by you model (code) and generated by entity framework.

Comment: Hm...what a lousy limitation. Code first is so much cleaner than the EDMX model, it's a shame they don't have these features implemented in both. They let you specify custom db initialization code, so even keeping the code first model in mind it would make sense to include this. Sigh...

Comment: Finally, 2 years later, it's possible to do it: you can acces the EDM from Code First. I've added an answer that links to an imcomplete implementation of TVFs and SPs mappings.

Answer (score 3):

As of EF 6.1 it's now possible to map functions, because now it's possiblw to acces the EDM from Code First.

Here is a sample of an implementation that allows to map TVFs and Stored Procedures, but with some limitations. It also uses EF 6 custom conventions.

Hopefully there will be soon more complete solutions:

https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/

*NOTE: you can use git to copy the code to your machine and modify/improve it*