# How to use Scalar Value functions in EntityFramework Query

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014, c#-6.0

I have a scalar valued function as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCustomersTime]
(
    @TimeSpanType char(1),
    @TimeSpan int,
    @CurrentUtc datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CustomersTime DATETIME; 

    SELECT @CustomersTime = CASE UPPER(@TimeSpanType)
       WHEN 'S' THEN DATEADD(Second, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
       WHEN 'I' THEN DATEADD(Minute, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
       WHEN 'H' THEN DATEADD(Hour, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
       WHEN 'D' THEN DATEADD(Day, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
       WHEN 'W' THEN DATEADD(Week, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
       WHEN 'M' THEN DATEADD(Month, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
       WHEN 'Q' THEN DATEADD(Quarter, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
       WHEN 'Y' THEN DATEADD(Year, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
       ELSE DATEADD(SECOND, @TimeSpan, @CurrentUtc)
    END;

    RETURN @CustomersTime
END
```

I would like to use this function in the Entity Framework Query. The query I would like to achieve is below:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.OrderDateUtc
FROM dbo.Customer c
--Other INNER JOINs
WHERE dbo.GetCustomersTime(c.[TimeSpanType], c.[TimeSpan], c.OrderDateUtc) > GetUtcDate()
--Additional Conditions
```

My entity framework query is:

```
(from c in _context.Customers
                 //additional joins
             where //how to use function
             select new
             {
                 c.CustomerId,
                 c.FirstName,
                 c.LastName,
                 c.OrderDateUtc
             }).ToList();
```

Some suggested to use a project and have the GetCustomersTime function in the EF query. But I could not find a real example. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you try to add the function to your ssdl of the edmx?

Comment: I dont have an edmx file. I have a DbContext class. I am using a code first approach even though we have a database already. I wish to know how can I add the function to my DbContext class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I should have searched it better. I found the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24167132/740756). The github link is [CodeFirstFunctions](https://github.com/moozzyk/CodeFirstFunctions).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Declare a function in the (SSDL) of your .edmx file. The name of the
   function must be the same as the name of the function declared in the
   database.
2. Add a corresponding method to a class in your application code and
   apply a `EdmFunctionAttribute` to the method.
3. Call the method in a LINQ to Entities query.

For more details check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/how-to-call-custom-database-functions).